# Multiple types of date recognition using antlr 4

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I would like to parse dates for these following types:

- 15/apr/2016
- 15th of apr

So this is my grammar:

```
date: formal_date|explicit_date|EOF;

formal_date:
     INT SEPARATOR month SEPARATOR INT
    | INT SEPARATOR month SEPARATOR INT4
    | INT SEPARATOR INT SEPARATOR INT4;

explicit_date:
         INT TH OF month
     ;

month : JAN | FEB | MAR | APR | MAY | JUN | JUL | AUG | SEP | OCT | NOV | DEC ;

number : FLOAT | INT | INT4 ;

// lexer rules

FLOAT : DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT+ ;

INT4 : DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT;
INT : DIGIT+;

JAN : [Jj][Aa][Nn] ;
FEB : [Ff][Ee][Bb] ;
MAR : [Mm][Aa][Rr] ;
APR : [Aa][Pp][Rr] ;
MAY : [Mm][Aa][Yy] ;
JUN : [Jj][Uu][Nn] ;
JUL : [Jj][Uu][Ll] ;
AUG : [Aa][Uu][Gg] ;
SEP : [Ss][Ee][Pp] ;
OCT : [Oo][Cc][Tt] ;
NOV : [Nn][Oo][Vv] ;
DEC : [Dd][Ee][Cc] ;

SEPARATOR : [/\\\-] ;

ON : [Oo][Nn] ;
TH : [Tt][Hh] ;
OF : [Oo][Ff] ;

fragment DIGIT : [0-9];
```

And these are the outputs of the antlr:

```
Parsing: 15/apr/2016
Tree: (date (formal_date 15 / (month apr) / 2016))

Parsing: 15th of apr
Tree: (date (explicit_date 15 th of (month apr)))
```

But If I pass a sentence like `birthday on 15th of apr` to antlr, it will parse a wrong tree:

```
Parsing : birthday on 15th of apr
Tree: (date th on 15 th of apr)
```

So Is there anyway to fix this problem? for example skipping the `th` in `birthday`?

Comment: Is this the complete grammar? How are you matching the `birthday` ?

Comment: @canSleepNow Yes. I just want to extract `(date (explicit_date 15 th of (month apr)))`  for inputs like birthday on 15th of apr or  playing football on 15th of apr etc.

Comment: I think I understand. The point is you can't use ANTLR4 in this way - to extract something directly. Everything needs to be matched in grammar, you can then skip it or use it. But you can't write `playing football` if there are not tokens to match this. You can, but you'll get errors :)

Comment: @canSleepNow Oh but how can [natty](http://natty.joestelmach.com/try.jsp) extract dates ? for example it can recognize date times for `birthday on 15th of apr`

Comment: I don't know how they did it. If I had to do it with antrl4, I would simply write a sort of "rest" lexer rule that matches all the other tokens (any other word not needed for the date) and skip it. So something like `REST: [A-Za-z]+ -> skip;` Of course you have to consider ambiguities etc..

Comment: @canSleepNow thanks, but on more question can i skip a word ? for example `'birthday' -> skip`

Comment: You can. But how many words would you need to skip? Would write all of them in the grammar? What if it's the whole dictionary? See what I'm getting at? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the grammar that works the way you want it to (sorry didn't have time to write the answer at the time when I wrote comments)

```
grammar testDate;

date: formal_date|explicit_date|EOF;

formal_date:
     INT SEPARATOR month SEPARATOR INT
    | INT SEPARATOR month SEPARATOR INT4
    | INT SEPARATOR INT SEPARATOR INT4;

explicit_date:
         INT TH OF month
     ;

month : JAN | FEB | MAR | APR | MAY | JUN | JUL | AUG | SEP | OCT | NOV | DEC ;

number : FLOAT | INT | INT4 ;

// lexer rules

FLOAT : DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT+ ;

INT4 : DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT;
INT : DIGIT+;

JAN : [Jj][Aa][Nn] ;
FEB : [Ff][Ee][Bb] ;
MAR : [Mm][Aa][Rr] ;
APR : [Aa][Pp][Rr] ;
MAY : [Mm][Aa][Yy] ;
JUN : [Jj][Uu][Nn] ;
JUL : [Jj][Uu][Ll] ;
AUG : [Aa][Uu][Gg] ;
SEP : [Ss][Ee][Pp] ;
OCT : [Oo][Cc][Tt] ;
NOV : [Nn][Oo][Vv] ;
DEC : [Dd][Ee][Cc] ;

SEPARATOR : [/\\\-] ;

//ON : [Oo][Nn];
TH : [Tt][Hh]' ' ;
ND : [Nn][Dd]' ' ;
RD : [Rr][Dd]' ' ;
OF : [Oo][Ff]' ';

fragment REST : [A-Za-z \n\t\r];
REST_L : REST+? -> skip;

fragment DIGIT : [0-9];
```

Of course there may be somethings missing depending on how you want to extend and expand. Few explanations

- lexer rule `REST_L` has `+?` for matching at the end, this is the
  non-greedy operator
- token `ON` is removed (commented out), since you didn't use it in
  any of the parser rules
- there is a space added for tokens `th,nd,rd,of` - just a trick I sometimes use to get what's needed. (The proper way to achieve this would be to use lexer mode, where we'd have mode when we know it's part of the date, and mode when it's not)

So for the input `birthday on 15th of apr` you get the following parse tree:

[image]